# Compare angular index variable in smarty tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smarty

I want to catch the first iteration in ng-repeat directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <div is-open="{if "[[$index]]" == 0}true{else}false{/if}">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Setting 0 as string also doesn't work. Comparing in angular also doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div is-open="{{$index == 0}}"></div>
```

Comment: Comment your answer please, the only code in not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use special property `$first` of `ng-repeat` with ternary operator. Like see below snippet

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <div is-open="($first) ? true : false">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I suppose smarty code will not work as you're expecting. Smarty is a server side programming language and angular runs on client side. In your query, smarty tags are unnecessary being called in angular directive. Above trick will work for you. 
There are also some couple of special properties available too. You can check them out [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)